# how to run grep from script and store output in a file in the destination directory from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

I am trying to filter out lines from a file through a bash script. I am able to find the path of the file from script location by running the command

```
Fgff=`find $D -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.gff"`
```

I can add a column to the found .gff file by running the command

```
   sed -i '1 s/$/\tsample/; 1! s/$/\t'${D##*/}'/' $Fpsi
```

However if I try to filter the file and write the output in another file in the same folder then its not working.

```
grep 'ENSG00000155657\|ENSG00000198947' $Fgff > "$Fgff$filtered"
```

I want to know why grep is not working?

How can I filter all the lines having substring ENSG00000155657 or ENSG00000198947 in file apple.gff at `./dira/dirb/apple.gff` and store it in `./dira/dirb/applefiltered.gff`?

thanks

Comment: Use `grep -E 'ENSG00000155657|ENSG00000198947'` and lose the backslash.  The `-E` turns on extended regular expressions (`egrep` mode for those of us who learned Unix in the last millennium).

Comment: In general, it is better to use `$(…)` instead of backticks to capture the output of a command.  There are also possible issues with spaces and other oddball characters in filenames that you might need to worry about.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks -E and removing / did the trick. File is made in the same directory besides original. Spent few hours before posting questions but glad sorted now.

Answer (score -1):

Providing that your $Fgff contains the correct filename, your grep command does exactly what you requested, searching for the string 'ENSG0000015565(7\|E)NSG00000198947' while you probably wanted '(ENSG00000155657)\|(ENSG00000198947)'.

Comment: That’s an unlikely interpretation of the original regular expression.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for correcting me, I revised my understanding of regexes.